# strip sides of a string in python

Tags: python, string, strip

I have a list like this:

> Tomato4439, >gi|224089052|ref|XP_002308615.1| predicted protein [Populus trichocarpa]

I want to strip the unwanted characters using python so the list would look like:
Tomato
Populus trichocarpa

I can do the following for the first one:

```
name = ">Tomato4439"
name = name.strip(">1234567890")
print name
Tomato
```

However, I am not sure what to do with the second one. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all lines constructed consistently?  If so, I see no reason to not just do a .split or similar approach to grab what is clearly bounded by square brackets

Comment: What are the rules that govern *which* chars you want to include, and which you don't?  (Without knowing that, it's hard to help you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given:

```
s='Tomato4439, >gi|224089052|ref|XP_002308615.1| predicted protein [Populus trichocarpa]'
```

this:

```
s = s.split()
[s[0].strip('0123456789,'), s[-2].replace('[',''), s[-1].replace(']','')]
```

will give you

```
['Tomato', 'Populus', 'trichocarpa']
```

It might be worth investigating regular expressions if you are going to do this frequently and the "rules" might not be that static as regular expressions are much more flexible dealing with the data in that case. For the sample problem you present though, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "Tomato4439, >gi|224089052|ref|XP_002308615.1| predicted protein [Populus trichocarpa]"
>>> match = re.match("^([a-zA-Z]+).*\[([a-zA-Z ]+)\].*",line)
>>> match.groups()
('Tomato', 'Populus trichocarpa')
```

edited to not include the `[]` on the 2nd part...  this should work for any thing that matches the pattern of your query (eg starts with name, ends with something in []) it would also match 
`"Tomato4439, >gi|224089052|ref|XP_002308615.1| predicted protein [Populus trichocarpa apples]"` for example

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
a = "Tomato4439, >gi|224089052|ref|XP_002308615.1| predicted protein [Populus trichocarpa]"
re.sub(r"^([A-Za-z]+).+\[([^]]+)\]$", r"\1 \2", a)
```

This gives

```
'Tomato Populus trichocarpa'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the strings you're trying to parse are consistent semantically, then your best option might be classifying the different "types" of strings you have, and then creating regular expressions to parse them using python's `re` module.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers were simpler than mine, but:

Here is one way to print the stuff that you don't want.

```
tag = "Tomato4439, >gi|224089052|ref|XP_002308615.1| predicted protein [Populus trichocarpa]"
import re, os
find = re.search('>(.+?) \[', tag).group(1)
print find
```

Gives you

```
gi|224089052|ref|XP_002308615.1| predicted protein
```

Then you can use the replace function to remove that from the original string. And the translate function to remove the extra unwanted characters.

```
tag2 = tag.replace(find, "")
tag3 = str.translate(tag2, None, ">[],")
print tag3
```

Gives you

```
Tomato4439  Populus trichocarpa
```

Comment: As a note, this RE syntax, (.+?) basically means 'what is here?'

Comment: When you have the substring to be removed you can use `original_string.replace(that_string, '')` to remove the unwanted portion.

Comment: How do you remove multiple unwanted portions at once using one replace  function? e.g. remove find, remove '[', remove ']', remove '>'

Comment: I think you can't in a simple way. To extract `'A B'` from `'A562, some string [B]'` using only `str.replace` you would have to replace `'562,some string[B]'` with `' B'`. But if you had the `'B'` part you could avoid the replace taking the alphabetic prefix of the string.